# Преобразование JSON в POJO начиная с определенного уровня вложенности

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

Есть система, отдающая по REST API здоровенный JSON. На нее я воздействовать не могу ни коем образом.

Из этого огромного JSON-а мне нужна только часть по определенному ключу.

Допустим из этого:

```
{
 "a":{
      "b":[.....]
     },
 "c":{.....},
 "r":{
     "d":{
          "e":{
               "f":[....],
               "g":[....]
              }
         },
      "m":{......}
   .....
   "z":{....}
}
```

Мне нужно сделать POJO структуру начиная с `r.d.e`.

Для того же GSON'а придется создавать как минимум всю ветку, что совершенно излишне (или я заблуждаюсь?)

Есть ли какие библиотеки, которые можно использовать совместно с `okhttp3` и которые позволяют организовать такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вручную разбирать весь JSON пока не дойдёте до нужного узла и только его парсить в объект. Типа как-то [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11428399/3212712):

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(HUGE_JSON_STRING).getAsJsonObject();
String stringToParseNoramlly = obj.get("r").get("d").get("e").getAsString();
EModel eModel = new Gson().fromJson(stringToParseNoramlly, EModel.class);
```

Comment: То чувство, когда час искал очки, а они на лбу были...

Comment: @rjhdby, свежий взгляд бывает полезен, да)